# Laravel Eloquent SELECT sortBy with limit 150 rows

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

sorry for newbie question. I want to get from table specific columns, order them by date and extract only 150 rows. I tried a lot of combinations. But i dont get the point how should it work:

```
public function get()
    {
        Excel::create('Bids-' . date("Y/m/d"), function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('Favourites', function($sheet) {
                $comments = Comment::select('auction_name','bid','lot_date','company', 'model_name_en', 'body','grade_en', 'mileage_num', 'model_year_en', 'start_price_en')->sortBy("lot_date", 'desc')->take(150)->get();
                $sheet->fromModel($comments);
            });
        })->download('xls');
    }
```

Please, can some one explain me what im doing wrong, why `sortBy` dont want to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$comments = Comment::select('auction_name','bid','lot_date','company', 'model_name_en', 'body','grade_en', 'mileage_num', 'model_year_en', 'start_price_en')->orderBy("lot_date", 'desc')->take(150)->get();
```

notice usage of `orderBy()` instead of `sortBy()`.

Comment: Please provide proper formatting and explain your answer

Comment: it did work actually,  the problem was in that i need to use `orderBy` in stead of `sortBy`

Answer (score 0):

Actually i find a solution, but i still hardly get it, why it didn't work in before.

This is the solution:

```
Excel::create('Bids-' . date("Y/m/d"), function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('Favourites', function($sheet) {

                $comments = Comment::select('auction_name','bid','lot_date','company', 'model_name_en', 'body','grade_en', 'mileage_num', 'model_year_en', 'start_price_en')->take(150)->get();
                $result = $comments->sortByDesc('lot_date');
                $sheet->fromModel($result);
            });
        })->download('xls');
```